# UWP Animate Shadow in XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I am playing around with Scale animation in Windows Community Toolkit and trying to animate Shadow when object scales.

first I thought that the Shadow would scale with the object and it didn't
then I tried to scale the shadow as well but that doesn't work

[image]

Here is my XAML

```html
 <controls:DropShadowPanel x:Name="DropShadowHolder" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40,31,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                               BlurRadius="20"
                               ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                               OffsetX="1"
                               OffsetY="1"
                               Color="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  ui:VisualExtensions.NormalizedCenterPoint="0.5">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                    <behaviors:StartAnimationAction Animation="{x:Bind ShadowScaleAnimationEnter}" />
                </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                    <behaviors:StartAnimationAction Animation="{x:Bind ShadowScaleAnimationExit}" />
                </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ani:Explicit.Animations>
                <ani:AnimationSet x:Name="ShadowScaleAnimationEnter">
                    <ani:ScaleAnimation From="1" To="1.2"/>
                </ani:AnimationSet>
                <ani:AnimationSet x:Name="ShadowScaleAnimationExit">
                    <ani:ScaleAnimation From="1.2" To="1"/>
                </ani:AnimationSet>
            </ani:Explicit.Animations>
            <Button Background="Gray"
          Width="100"
          Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ui:VisualExtensions.NormalizedCenterPoint="0.5">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                        <behaviors:StartAnimationAction Animation="{x:Bind ScaleAnimationEnter}" />
                    </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                        <behaviors:StartAnimationAction Animation="{x:Bind ScaleAnimationExit}" />
                    </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ani:Explicit.Animations>
                    <ani:AnimationSet x:Name="ScaleAnimationEnter">
                        <ani:ScaleAnimation From="1" To="1.2"/>
                    </ani:AnimationSet>
                    <ani:AnimationSet x:Name="ScaleAnimationExit">
                        <ani:ScaleAnimation From="1.2" To="1"/>
                    </ani:AnimationSet>
                </ani:Explicit.Animations>
            </Button>
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

> UWP Animate Shadow in XAML

That's interesting, please feel free post it to Community Tool Kit issue box. If you don't mind implement this animation within code behind, we suggest you use `SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation` and `ThemeShadow` to approach.

For example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ThemeShadow x:Name="SharedShadow" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Button
        x:Name="MyButton"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Background="Gray"
        Loaded="Button_Loaded"
        PointerEntered="element_PointerEntered"
        PointerExited="element_PointerExited"
        Shadow="{StaticResource SharedShadow}" />
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    SharedShadow.Receivers.Add(BackgroundGrid);
    MyButton.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 32);
   
}

Compositor _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation;

private void CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(float finalValue)
{
    if (_springAnimation == null)
    {
        _springAnimation = _compositor.CreateSpringVector3Animation();
        _springAnimation.Target = "Scale";
    }

    _springAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3(finalValue);
}

private void element_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale up to 1.5
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.5f);
    (sender as UIElement).CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(MyButton.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(MyButton.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}

private void element_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale back down to 1.0
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.0f);
    (sender as UIElement).CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(MyButton.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(MyButton.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nico, tried your example and I do not see the shadow at all, I am missing something?

Comment: Here is sample [code](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App7), please check it.

Comment: Apparently, my WIndows lost Windows effects.... fixed it with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Dwm ForceEffectMode set to 2

Comment: Still, not a great solution as I change the Cornet Radius of the Button it looks bad. Shadow does not respect it... :(

Comment: That's interesting, I saw that, I will report it, thanks for your feed back.

Comment: We're working on improved Shadow support in the 7.1 version of the Toolkit, so I'll have to test out your example. Haven't gotten to hooking into our Explicit Animations yet, but should in the next week hopefully: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/pull/4179